# Rails, Custom Folders and Namespaces

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm running Rails 3.2.7,

I have a folder '/app/jobs'

and the following in my 'config/application.rb' file

```
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{Rails.root}/app/jobs)
```

And everything is okay.

However if I want to namespace my classes eg

```
class Jobs::UpdateGameStatus
  #methods etc
end
```

Rather than

```
class UpdateGameStatus
  #methods etc
end
```

Then I get

> uninitialized constant Jobs (NameError)

It's not the end of the world but I'd love to know why...

Comment: everything under app is autoloaded, no need to add anything in config

Comment: try to add the following:

in `/app/job/jobs.rb`:

    module Jobs;

    end

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed it in the end, wrapping all my classes with a Jobs module was what I needed to do.

my files were located in 'app/jobs'

and looked like this

```
module Jobs
  class JobName
    #methods etc
  end
end
```

and are used like so

```
Jobs::JobName.method(args)
```

Comment: `class Jobs::JobName` does actually work, but only if `module Jobs` has already been defined elsewhere. So the approach you show here is usually better.

Answer (score 1):

I know you have already sorted this out, and this is old, but in ruby, it is also possible to declare the namespaced class directly using `class Jobs::JobName`.  It's a little less typing, and achieves the same result.

Edit: As @D-side pointed out, Jobs has to already be defined.  My own code that uses this is based around STI, which presumes that the previous class/module I am extending already exists.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/tzVJXIB.png -- am I doing something wrong then? Doesn't work for me, Ruby is up-to-date.

Comment: I should say it only works if Jobs is already defined.  I guess I assumed that `Jobs` was either already a class or a module.  Thanks for pointing that out, @D-side.

Comment: Yep, reflect that in your answer, please.