# Naming conventions for custom dir under /app/ in a Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have question about naming conventions and autoloading.

I want to have a presenter ItemPresenter in `app/presenters/items/item_presenter.rb`

My understanding was that I can just create that file like this:

```
module Items
  class ItemPresenter
  end
end
```

But when I do this and try to call the presenter as `Items::ItemPresenter` I get `uninitialized constant` error:

```
uninitialized constant Items::ItemPresenter

def show
   @presenter = Items::ItemPresenter.new # this is the highlighted line of my Controller
```

EDIT: [Rails, Custom Folders and Namespaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13510949/rails-custom-folders-and-namespaces) is not duplicate because it's about different dir structure `jobs/smth.rb` while I am trying to implement `presenters/items/item_presenter.rb` (1 more level)

EDIT2: neither it works from rails console: `NameError: uninitialized constant Items::ItemPresenter`

EDIT2: I tried doing this as suggested:

```
module Presenters
  module Items
    class ItemPresenter
      def test
        "hello"
      end
    end
  end
end
```

And `@presenter = Presenters::Items::ItemPresenter.new` in my controller:

```
 uninitialized constant TrialsController::Presenters
```

It seems like Rails do not see that directory at all.

EDIT3: Created a sample app https://github.com/dontlookforme/test_app

EDIT4: Figured it out. I screwed up the file name (see the answer I've posted)

Comment: can you post the exact error message you're getting? I created this in a dummy app and am able to call `Items::ItemPresenter` in my rails console

Comment: Do you need a module Presenters to contain module Items and Class ItemPresenter?

Comment: @sixty4bit ugh. doesn't work even in rails console for me :( updated the question

Comment: @MichaelGaskill tried that, doesn't work. See the update pls

Comment: This might have to do with the fact that in your application's config/applicaiton.rb file, you have to specify something like:

      `config.paths.add('app/presenters', eager_load: true)`

Comment: @user1556912 any chance you could replicate in a dummy app and make it public on github?

Comment: @sixty4bit just did, here https://github.com/dontlookforme/test_app

I gotta be missing something simple >_<

Comment: thanks @user1556912! that helped me find the problem. see my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer but it's necessary to see @user1556912's sample app (link in the original question) to see what happened.

The problem is that the filename is `items_presenter.rb` (plural) but the class name is `ItemPresenter` (singular).

As I pointed out in a comment on @Anthony E's answer, Rails will autoload everything in the `/app` dir, so it's not necessary explicitly to tell Rails about these files. However, along with namespaces matching dir hierarchies, the names of the classes must also match the names of the files exactly. In this case, I was able to get the class to load in the rails console by renaming `items_presenter.rb` to `item_presenter.rb`.

Going back to @Anthony E's answer, though, I do agree that the `Items::` namespace seems superfluous here. I would just do `app/presenters/item_presenter.rb`.

Answer (score 0):

`app/presenters/` is the conventional path to store presenters. In fact, you can probably go without folder nesting for items:

> app/presenters/item_presenter.rb

You'll need to update the module path accordingly:

```
  module Presenters
    class ItemPresenter
      def test
        "hello"
      end
    end
  end
```

Then, you can tell Rails to automatically load this file in your `application.rb`:

```
config.autoload_paths << '#{config.root}/app/presenters'
```

Comment: It shouldn't be necessary to explicitly autoload paths in `/app`. Rails already loads everything in that dir (one benefit of putting new files there instead of `/lib`)

Answer (score 0):

Ugh. The thing I was doing wrong is the file name.
I named the preseter file `items_presenter.rb` but the class had singular Item in the name `ItemPresenter`.

Fixed that and everything started working.

Thanks for the help guys!

Comment: @sixty4bit ahha that timing :D You've posted while I was typing. Thank you very much!